# How many points are needed to uniquely define an Euler spiral?

Tags: calculus

Also commonly known as a [clothoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral) or cornu spiral, it's the curve defined parametrically as
$$x=\int_0^t \cos(u^2)du$$
$$y=\int_0^t \sin(u^2)du$$

or simply using the complex plane as coordinates:

$$z=x+yi=\int_0^t e^{iu^2}du$$

[image: euler spiral]

In the same respect of how a singular unique circle can be defined by three known points,

> How many points are needed to uniquely define an Euler spiral? The spiral can be translated, scaled proportionally, and rotated.

I.e; How many points are needed to deduce unique values for $z_0$, $a$, and $\theta$ such that $z_0+a\int_0^t e^{i(u^2+\theta)}du$ (a function of $t$) is the only Euler spiral that runs through all points?

---

I'm afraid I'm dumb-struck with where to start. Would the spiraling-convergence as $t\rightarrow\pm\infty$ imply there are an infinite set of solutions regardless of how many points are known?

Comment: There is a countable infinity, and then there is a continuum infinity. The latter is a great deal greater. In short, no, I don't expect a solution to always exist for arbitrarily many points, or for 5, for that matter.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Intuitively, there's always a solution for 3 points or less. But if there isn't one for say, 5, like you conjecture, then the minimum number of points must be finite, right?

Comment: You have four variables (translation in X and Y, scaling, and rotation), hence four points should be just enough.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Aha that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for making me aware.